# where CategoryId = 75 and (BrandId = 12 or BrandId = 3) equivalent Linq to Entity

Tags: entity-framework-4

I need to filter the data using a filter
where CategoryId = 75 and (BrandId = 12 or BrandId = 3)
but the equivalent Linq to Entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming C# and same named columns, you filter your context using:

```
.Where(w=>w.CategoryId==75 && (w.BrandId==12 || w.BrandId==3))
```